# how can i mock specific embedded method inside interface

Tags: go

I have this code and I wanna write a unit tests for update function.

how can i mock `FindByUsername` function ?

I try to overwrite `u.FindByUsername` but it's doesn't work.

also, I can write some function to give `u *UserLogic` and `userName string` as input parameters and execute `u.FindByUsername()` and mock this function but it's not a clean solution I need a better solution for mocking methods inside `UserOperation` interface.

```
package logic

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    dataStore = map[string]*User{
        "optic": &User{
            Username: "bla",
            Password: "ola",
        },
    }
)

//UserOperation interface
type UserOperation interface {
    Update(info *User) error
    FindByUsername(userName string) (*User, error)
}

//User struct
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

//UserLogic struct
type UserLogic struct {
    UserOperation
}

//NewUser struct
func NewUser() UserOperation {
    return &UserLogic{}
}

//Update method
func (u *UserLogic) Update(info *User) error {
    userInfo, err := u.FindByUsername(info.Username)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(userInfo.Username, userInfo.Password)
    fmt.Println("do some update logic !!!")
    return nil
}

//FindByUsername method
func (u *UserLogic) FindByUsername(userName string) (*User, error) {
    userInfo := &User{}
    var exist bool
    if userInfo, exist = dataStore[userName]; !exist {
        return nil, errors.New("user not found")
    }
    return userInfo, nil
}
```

**Update**

I try to mock function with this code

```
func TestUpdate2(t *testing.T) {
    var MockFunc = func(userName string) (*User, error) {
        return &User{Username:"foo", Password:"bar"},nil
    }
    user := NewUser()
    user.FindByUsername = MockFunc
    user.Update(&User{Username:"optic", Password:"ola"})
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to mock that function so you can test Update? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: yes, i try to mock ``` func TestUpdate(t *testing.T) {
 var MockFunc = func(userName string) (*User, error) {
  return &User{Username:"foo", Password:"bar"},nil
 }
 user := NewUser()
 user.FindByUsername = MockFunc
 user.Update(&User{Username:"optic", Password:"ola"})
}``` but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, instead update your question. You cannot assign functions to methods in Go. You can write a mock implementation of the interface `UserOperation` and use that during testing.

Comment: @RezaOptic take a look at this: https://play.golang.com/p/G7dutF3Tc74 however this is not really a mock, I would call it a fake or a stub, mocks usually allow you to specify the methods you expect to be called alongside with their arguments and return values and then at the end of the test check whether they were actually called. You may want to give this a try: https://github.com/golang/mock

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two levels of abstraction in your `UserOperation` interface: `Update` depends on `FindByUsername`. To make `Update` testable you need to inject the `UserFinder` functionality into your `Update` method. You can do this e.g. by defining a field in the `UserLogic` struct:

```
type UserOperation interface {
    Update(info *User) error
}

type UserFinder func(userName string) (*User, error)

type UserLogic struct {
    UserOperation
    FindByUsername UserFinder
}

//NewUser struct
func NewUser() *UserLogic { // return structs, accept interfaces!
    return &UserLogic{
        findByUsername: FindByUsername
    }
}

func (u *UserLogic) Update(info *User) error {
    userInfo, err := u.findByUsername(info.Username)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(userInfo.Username, userInfo.Password)
    fmt.Println("do some update logic !!!")
    return nil
}

func FindByUsername(userName string) (*User, error) {
    userInfo := &User{}
    var exist bool
    if userInfo, exist = dataStore[userName]; !exist {
        return nil, errors.New("user not found")
    }
    return userInfo, nil
}
```